# D3: How to stick text with dynamic height to bottom of SVG element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to display some text with dynamic content to be displayed at the bottom below my SVG chart. The text sometimes only consists of one line, sometimes of two. Right now, if there are two lines, the second line is cut off because it is outside of the drawing area.

The text is drawn like this:

```
chart.append("text")
    .attr("class", "source")
    .attr("x", MARGINS.left + 10)
    .attr("y", HEIGHT - 5)
    .attr("width", WIDTH - MARGINS.right)
    .text(somedynamiccontent());
```

So the problem is, that the "y" attribute refers to the top of the text box, but I want it to point to the bottom of the element so that the text element only "grows" up- and not downwards. Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this? I already tried out `alignment-baseline` property, but i think that's not what i'm looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Normally the y attribute **is** the bottom of the text box unless you've altered it via dominant-baseline or alignment-baseline.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the svg coordinate system has its origin at the upper left corner (https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#initial-coordinate-system). Thats why i thought the anchor points of x and y are the upper left corner of the current element as well.

Comment: Clearly a gold SVG badge and 40,000 lines of code in Firefox's SVG  component don't count for much these days. [For most uses of Latin text (i.e., writing-mode:lr, text-anchor:start and alignment-baseline:baseline) the alignment-point in the glyph will be the intersection of left edge of the glyph cell (or some other glyph-specific x-axis coordinate indicating a left-side origin point) with the Latin baseline of the glyph.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement)